# How could I fetch assets files from a project inside my application?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-http

I have an application (called http-app) inside the main project, which I am testing angular communication service using HTTP, following this [guide](https://angular.io/guide/http).

At the assets folder there is a config.json file.

[image]

And at config.service.ts I am trying to get the config.json file:

```
configUrl = 'assets/config.json'

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getConfig(): Observable<Config> {
  return this.http.get<Config>(this.configUrl)
    .pipe(
      retry(3),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

But the file was not found. Result:

[image]

For more clarification about the folder structure:

```
main-project
  projects
    http-app
      assets
        config.json <----
      src
        app
          config.service.ts
        ...
  src
    app
    ...
```

So how could I fetch config.json file inside a project assets folder?

Answer (score 0):

your path relative to the root directory would be `"projects/http-app/assets/config.json"`

otherwise you can try up two dir `"../../assets/config.json"`

Can you log the value of this var?
Im not sure your app structure if your using node modules you can try import

```
import config from "projects/http-app/assets/config.json"
```

Comment: Didn't worked...maybe because it's a http/get request